# BufferedReader only reading the first few characters

Tags: java, file, file-io, bufferedreader, filereader

So I have a one line text file that is being read however only the first few characters are actually being read. My code for reading in is as follows:

```
try {
 BufferedReader freqReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(letterFrequency));
     String temp = freqReader.readLine();
     System.out.println(temp);
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("IO Exception");
}
```

Where letterFrequency has been assigned to the file **frequency.txt** in the constructor. This contains the singular line:

```
e 12.7t 9.0a 8.167o 7.7i 7.3n 6.75s 6.33r 6.0h 6.094d 4.253l 4.025u 2.758c 2.782m 2.406f 2.228y 1.974w 2.360g 2.015p 1.929b 1.492v 0.978k 0.772x 0.150q 0.1j 0.153z 0.074
```

However only **e 12.7** is printed out and I have no idea why. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Usually you read in a while loop until no more text is found, and you also need to close the reader when done with it, as this flushes the stream.

Comment: Okay but having a while loop should matter here since it’s all on one line right? And I’ll be sure to close the reader.

Comment: Close / flush that reader -- what happens?

Comment: Are you _absolutely_ sure the file is a single line?  If the file uses Unix line endings and you display it on a Window system the newlines won't show up as newlines.

Comment: You are only reading one line, and you are mistaken about what is in the file. I don't know what all this nonsense is about flushing an input stream. @HovercraftFullOfEels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out @Jim Garrison was correct in his comment that it was using Unix line endings that were not showing up correctly on my system, so I have used different code that reads multiple lines.